# How do you calculate the test statistic of a hypothesis test with more than 1 parameter?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, econometrics

I am interested in testing the following hypothesis: 
\begin{align} 
\newcommand{\var}{\rm Var} 
\newcommand{\cov}{\rm Cov}
\newcommand{\se}{\rm se}
H_0\!:\ B_2 + B_3 &=   1  \\
H_1\!:\ B_2 + B_3 &\ne 1
\end{align}
How do you find the test statistic for a hypothesis about the sum of two independent variables? I'm very confused.

The model is: 
\begin{align}
\ln(y)  &= −3.33846  + 1.49877 x_1 +  0.489858 x_2  \\
\se(B_2) &= 0.539803  \\
\se(B_3) &= 0.102043
\end{align}
*this is a double log

I am guessing the test statistic is:
\begin{align}
\frac{B_2 + B_3 -1}{\se(B_2)+\se(B_3)} &=  \frac{1.49877  +  0.489858  -1}{0.539803+0.102043}  \\
                                     &= 1.540
\end{align}
This yields a p-value = 0.071, so I don't reject at the 95% significance. Apparently both are wrong.

I have seen this formula:
\begin{align}
H_0\!: B_2 + CB_3 &= 1  \\
H_1\!: B_2 + \ \ \ B_3  &\ne 1
\end{align}
Which leads to:
\begin{align}
t &= \frac{B_1+CB_2-a}{se(B_2+cB_3)}  \\
\  \\
\se(B_2+cB_3) &= \sqrt{\var(B_2)+\var(B_3)+2C\times \cov(B_2,B_3)}
\end{align}
But I have no idea what $c$ is.

---

*Update:* $C$ turned out to be irrelevant for this question.

This ended up being the answer:

$$t=\frac{1.49877+0.489858-1}{\sqrt{0.291387+0.0104129+2(-0.0384272)}=2.084}, \quad p = 0.059$$

Insufficient evidence to reject null at the 95% significance level

Comment: I don't get why the hypotheses are $H_{0}: \beta_{2} + \beta_{3} = 1$ vs $H_{1}: \beta_{2} + \beta_{3} \neq 1$

Comment: what don't you get? $B_2$ and $B_3$ is the coefficient of $x_1$ and $x_2$

Comment: Yes, I know. I do not understand why you test the hypothesis that $\beta_{2}$ and $\beta_{3}$ should sum up to one.

Comment: Well this model is a log-log model which finds elasticities. This could be a about the elasticity of the two to be 1. Do you wave any ideas for the question? The idea that they sum up really confuses me.

Comment: I still don't see a clear question in this post. What are you trying to ask?  Do you want to know how to test a linear hypothesis in a multiple regression model?

Comment: Whuber i'm trying to ask how to find the test statistic for a test with a hypothesis $B_2 + B_2  = 3$ the answer i got was put down as wrong

Comment: Are the $B_i$ "independent variables" or are they *coefficients* of independent variables in a regression model?  I would guess the latter.  In that case, you might want to re-examine your implicit assumption that the standard error of the estimate of $B_2+B_3$ is the sum of the standard errors of estimate of $B_2$ and $B_3$: that is only rarely possible. It is confusing to your readers--and possibly to you--that you appear to use the same notation for the estimates as you do for the parameters themselves.

Comment: Of course they independent variables! Why would i equate for their standard error!!!!  Does it matter that it's rare? When i'm just asking how to find the test statistic... Please re-open my question.

Comment: 1 orthogonal comment: there will be a covariance between your parameter estimates. You will need to take that into account. The denominator would be something like sqrt{Var(B1)+Var(B2)-2Cov(B1,B2)}.

Comment: Thank you gung for actually having a valid answer to the question!!! It was very helpful. I went on gretl and on my OLS i went to covariance matrix and used your denominator which i had already found at the back of my text book. $t=\frac{1.49877+0.489858-1}{\sqrt{0.291387+0.0104129+2(-0.0384272)}=2.084}$ p-value = 0.059

Comment: Since you now appear to be able to answer your question you should answer it (or at least outline the approach) in an answer, not in your question. You should also clarify your question so it asks a question to which the resulting posted answer is an answer.

Comment: Just to point this out to you: You say "Of course they independent variables!" and then you calculate the covariance to something non-zero. This is a contradiction (meaning it's impossible) and it may be useful for you to think about that.

Comment: -3... Man, stats stack exchange can be so mean... I really gave gave a lot of effort writing this question to demonstrate that i did give a lot effort before asking. Didn't they say there's no bad question? And i feel this particular question had merit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(I am turning my comment into an answer so that this thread isn't counted as officially unanswered.  I actually hadn't realized that this was the answer that was wanted, I thought my point was orthogonal to the question.)*

You are performing a simultaneous test of two parameters.  Often that would be done by dropping the variables and performing a nested model test.  In your case, you are trying this using the standard errors, not as a nested model test.  To do that, you need to take the covariance of your parameters into consideration (in addition, *variances* add, not SEs).  Thus, the denominator would be:
$$
\sqrt{{\rm Var}(\hat\beta_2) + {\rm Var}(\hat\beta_3) - 2{\rm Cov}(\hat\beta_2, \hat\beta_3)}
$$
The covariance of your parameter estimates is not typically outputted by statistical software.  It comes from the variance-covariance matrix of the betas, which the software will have calculated as part of the process of fitting the model.  It should be possible to get that information, but how will differ depending on the software you use; in `R`, for example, you would call `vcov(model_fit_object)`.

Comment: Thank you gung this was very helpful and much appreciated.